# How to stop code when a condition is met c#, Debuging

Tags: c#, vba, debugging

I can't seem to find anything in C# that does this. I went through pages on MSDN but could not find anything. I know there the [Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx), but I don't see how you could use this for debuging?

ie, if you do this in VBA, the code stops for you and then you can debug from that point.

```
Dim ID As Long

      ID = 1001

      If ID = 1001 Then Stop
```

Is there a function in C# that will perform the same as `Stop` in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Debugger.Break()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

```
long ID;
ID = 1001;
if(ID == 1001)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I can't accept for a few more minutes, but this answers my question.

Comment: `Debug.Assert(ID != 1001);` is a bit cleaner if there isn't anything else in the `if` statement.